# LG UltraFine 5K Display connected to a MacBook Pro mid 2015 - Webcam/Mic/Speaker not working

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have an LG UltraFine 5K Display connected to a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015).
I am using a Thunderbolt 2 -> 3 adaptor to connect to the monitor (and the display works just fine).
The issue is that my Mac doesn't seem to recognise the webcam/mic/speakers that are built into the monitor.

Does the Monitor support webcam/mic/speakers from a thunderbolt 2 <-> 3 adaptor? If so any suggestions as to what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Monitor support webcam/mic/speakers from a thunderbolt 2 <-> 3 adaptor?

No.  [According to the specifications](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27md5kl-b-5k-uhd-led-monitor), it's a *Thunderbolt 3* monitor that provides connectivity.  You need a Thunderbolt 3 port.  The adapter only allows you to convert Thunderbolt 3 to 2 or 1 but it doesn't give you any more bandwidth than what you have on your existing MacBook.

You have enough bandwidth to drive the display, but not enough to drive all the peripheral devices connected to it.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought (I just wanted to confirm this). Do you know of any other solution I could use? Like is there some kind of external device that I could use with my old mac that could get all the peripherals to work? Or is this just a case of (you have to have thunderbolt 3 ports)?

Comment: You could try connecting a second USB cable from your Mac.  You'll need a USB-C male (monitor) to a USB-A male (laptop).  The most you'll get is USB 3.0, and not 3.1 or 3.2, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - gave that a try: The speakers and mic worked (but not the webcam). Also more importantly - the monitor itself was not recognised over USB-A -> USB-C :)

Comment: I can’t see the monitor being recognized from a USB port. The Monitor itself is not a USB device and it gets identified via the EDID data sent over the video connection. The connecting the USB cable is for the ancillary downstream devices. That webcam may require Thunderbolt or USB 3 to work properly